# How to write proper insert query with select subquery returning more than one row?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert, subquery

I have a problem with SQL. I looked all over stackoverflow and didn't find a solution for my problem. I have an insert statement which selects from different table where in "where" statement it looks in different table, etc.

There is a problem, that one of the subqueries return more than one value. What I need to achieve: there will be inserted two (or more, depends how much it will return) rows in the designated table.

Example with error, what I'mtrying to achieve:

```
create database tst;
/*1*/
create table person_account_table(
per_id varchar(50),
acct_id varchar(50)
);
insert into person_account_table(per_id, acct_id)
values('123','123');
insert into person_account_table(per_id, acct_id)
values('321','321');
insert into person_account_table(per_id, acct_id)
values('321','363');
/*1*/

/*2*/
create table person_id_table(
per_id varchar(50),
per_nbr varchar(50),
type_cd varchar(50)
);
insert into person_id_table(per_id, per_nbr, type_cd)
values ('123', 'zx32', 'good');
insert into person_id_table(per_id, per_nbr, type_cd)
values ('123', '32zx', 'pklx');
insert into person_id_table(per_id, per_nbr, type_cd)
values ('321', '35xcz', 'good');
insert into person_id_table(per_id, per_nbr, type_cd)
values ('321', 'fes235', 'pklx');
/*2*/

/*3*/
create table table_one(
au_id varchar(50),
type_cd varchar(50),
acct_id varchar(50)
);
insert into table_one(au_id, type_cd, acct_id)
values('1', 'e-pg', '321');
insert into table_one(au_id, type_cd, acct_id)
values('2', 'e-pg', '363');
insert into table_one(au_id, type_cd, acct_id)
values('3', 'e-pg', '123');
/*3*/

/*4*/
create table table_two(
per_nbr varchar(50),
ob_nbr varchar(50),
flag varchar(1)
);
insert into table_two(per_nbr, ob_nbr, flag)
values('zx32', 'dfas', 'N');
insert into table_two(per_nbr, ob_nbr, flag)
values('zx32', 'dfsvgd', 'P');
insert into table_two(per_nbr, ob_nbr, flag)
values('zx32', 'dsfds', 'N');
insert into table_two(per_nbr, ob_nbr, flag)
values('zx32', 'sdfdsf', 'P');

insert into table_two(per_nbr, ob_nbr, flag)
values('35xcz', 'dhf', 'N');
insert into table_two(per_nbr, ob_nbr, flag)
values('35xcz', 'tes', 'N');
insert into table_two(per_nbr, ob_nbr, flag)
values('35xcz', 'dfgdf', 'P');
insert into table_two(per_nbr, ob_nbr, flag)
values('35xcz', 'ehdhs', 'P');
/*4*/

-- table in which I want to inser data
create table result_table(
obj_nbr varchar(50),
au_id varchar(50)
);
```

**insert statement:**

```
insert into result_table (obj_nbr, au_id)
select tt.ob_nbr,
(
    select to1.au_id 
    from table_one to1 
    where to1.acct_id in
        (
            select pat.acct_id
            from person_account_table pat
            where pat.per_id in
            (
                select pit.per_id
                from person_id_table pit
                where pit.per_nbr = tt.per_nbr and
                pit.type_cd in ('good')
            )
        )
)
from table_two tt
where tt.flag = 'N';
```

And I get in result: **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

In this particular example, I get this error, because per_id = 321 has two different account. And each account gets it's own au_id from table_one.
How can I rewrite this query, that it will not crash, but insert two rows in the result table?

Comment: how does `tt.ob_nbr` relate to the information returned in your second column which is returning the multiple values? is your intention that each au_id found in your nested query will have a row for each `tt.ob_nbr`?  I'm having trouble following what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Putting subselects into the select portion of a query is usually very indicative of a problem.  This should be avoided.  You need to move your join logic into your `from`.  This looks like a pretty straight forward inner join unless i'm missing something in the nested subselects.

Comment: Additionally this looks overly nested with the several in statements, it seems that this could easily be refactored into joins, which i would think be easier to follow.

Comment: Yes, each au_id will have tt.ob_nbr.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  How does `table_two` join to `table_one`?  On which column are they the same?  (Or if they are not, which table does `table_two` relate to?)

Comment: `Table_two` relate to `person_id_table` by `table_two.per_nbr` = `person_id_table.per_nbr`.

Than table `person_id_table` relates to `person_account_table` by `person_id_table.per_id` = `person_account_table.per_id`

And `person_account_table` relates to `table_one` by `person_account_table.acct_id` = `table_one.acct_id`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution using inner joins.  It [returns the same result as @Dimitry](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06621/5) but does not use SQL89 syntax.  (very old)

```
insert into result_table (obj_nbr, au_id)
select 
  tt.ob_nbr, 
  to1.au_id 
from 
  table_one to1 
  inner join person_account_table pat on to1.acct_id = pat.acct_id
  inner join person_id_table pit on pat.per_id = pit.per_id
  inner join table_two tt on tt.per_nbr = person_id_table.per_nbr
where 
  pit.type_cd in ('good')
  and tt.flag = 'N';
```

Comment: I suspect that you have some junk data in your sample tables, which is why you get 6 rows instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be turned to this:

```
insert into result_table (obj_nbr, au_id)
select tt.ob_nbr,
       to1.au_id
  from person_account_table pat,
       person_id_table pit,
       table_one to1,
       table_two tt
 where pat.per_id = pit.per_id
   and pit.per_nbr = tt.per_nbr
   and to1.acct_id = pat.acct_id
   and pit.type_cd in ('good')
   and tt.flag = 'N';
```

But it returns 6 rows (check on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06621/2)).

**EDIT**
As Dave Costa noted in comments, my query can produce more rows in a case of duplicates. I didn't study your test data, because it is quite complicated, but you have a lot of rows with duplicates in columns, which are used to connect tables. It can be reason of your error and redundant rows in mine. So it can be one of two possibilities: your query should really return 6 rows or you need more conditions to specify what you need. In second case it will depend on meaning of your data and desired result.

Comment: This looks correct to me.  Would like to know why someone downvoted it.  Strictly speaking it is not logically equivalent to the OP's subquery approach - if there are duplicate `per_id` or `acct_id` values a join will produce multiple rows where an `IN` condition would produce only one - but I suspect it is a valid assumption that there are no duplicates, although the table definitions given don't have any relevant constraints.